Using semicolon in $Post still produces output
This code:
$Post = (# /. T -> 0) (1 - T) + T  (# /. T -> 1) &;

makes output
Null (1 - T) + Null T

Why?

As you are using "Set" or "=" the LHS is evaluated and evaluate to this output.

@DanielHuber with := it also outputs the same. Also, there is semicolon at the end.

You are right, this ist strange.

@DanielHuber did you try it? Is it the same for you? Not a problem with my installation?

Yes, I tried it in version 14.0 and 14.1 and it evaluates despite ":=".

There is nothing weird going on. When you evaluate your code, the $Post is already applied to its output! So the result is the same as applying your function to Null:
(* Clear your $Post *)
$Post =.

(* Apply your function to Null *)
((# /. T -> 0) (1 - T) + T (# /. T -> 1) &)[Null]
(* Null (1 - T) + Null T *)

Let me convince you with a simpler example:
$Post = Echo;
(* >> Null *)

If you want to fix this, you have to change your function such that it will map $\rm Null \mapsto Null$, for example:
$Post = If[# =!= Null, (# /. T -> 0) (1 - T) + T (# /. T -> 1)] &;


Why does not this code output anything? $Post = (# /. T -> 0) + T (D[#, T] /. T -> 0) &;?

Apply it to Null, and you will see that the result is Null. Hence, it is not displayed.

Why the second function does not output T Null?

Why would it? D[Null, T] is 0, and Null + 0 is Null.

Is there a way to fix this?

@Anixx, please see my edit.
